# Psake - Running same task multiple times

Tags: deployment, psake

I'm creating a build/deploy script for our website. Our process currently is a bit convoluted as it requires to start website with a webconfig setup to update our schema. Then we switch off the site, change webconfig not to update schema anymore and we start it again.

Because of repetitiveness of tasks our -taskList couple of tasks more than once.

eg.

```
Invoke-Psake (Join-Path $env:currentDir "\tasks\iis_app_deploy.ps1") `
-taskList ValidateProperties,StopApplicationPool,<random stuff>,StartApplicationPool,StopApplicationPool,StartApplicationPool,PutBackInLoadBalancer
```

**In this tasks list, each tasks gets excuted once and once only. Is there any way of specifying psake to run tasks without checking whether they have ran before or not?**

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my own question. **Nesting**.

Those were the steps;

1. Pull deployment process into smaller steps (in my case two)
2. Create a wrapper Task
3. Use Invoke-Psake in those to get it to work.

This is an example code;

```
task BackendDeployment -depends     ValidateProperties{
    # Deploy and update schema
    $self = Join-Path ($env:scriptPath) "tasks\iis_app_deploy.ps1"
    Write-Output "Running schema changes"
    Invoke-Psake $self  -TaskList   StopApplicationPool,`
                                    MSDeploy,`
                                    CopyLicenses,`
                                    CopyConfigs,`
                                    UpdateConfigForSchemaChanges,`
                                    StartApplicationPool,`
                                    WarmUpApplications, `
                                    WaitForAction `
                        -properties $properties
    Write-Output "Running final deployment"
    Invoke-Psake $self -TaskList    StopApplicationPool,`
                                    CopyConfigs,`
                                    StartApplicationPool,`
                                    WarmUpApplications `
                        -properties $properties
}
```